# OpenSSL EVP API datatypes, comparing known ciphertext with generated ciphertext

Tags: c, openssl, hex, aes, cbc-mode

Disclaimer: I am working on a SEED lab for homework; I don't need help with the implementation, but I would like to get some assistance on how to compare generated ciphertexts from AES_128_CBC with the given ciphertext I have.

In this task, we know that a key for AES was generated with srand(), and we know what time window the file was created. I computed the starting seed, so I can generate all keys from the starting seed until the end of the time window.

Next all that needs to be done is use the openSSL API to perform aes_128_cbc on the plaintext with the computed key and given initialization vector.

I used example code from openSSL here: [Symmetric enrycption and decription](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) to perform the aes-128-cbc algorithm. In my code I have initialized the known plaintext and ciphertext and IV as unsigned char arrays. The problem is when I generate a ciphertext to compare with my known ciphertext, I can never get a match, and I have a feeling it is because of the way I have formatted the input.

Below is the code I am using to initialize the plaintext, ciphertext, IV, generate the keys and ciphertext:

```
void main(){
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();


    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char key[7201][KEYSIZE];

    unsigned char iv[] = "09080706050403020100A2B2C2D2E2F2";
    unsigned char plaintext[] = "255044462D312E350A25D0D4C5D80A34";
    unsigned char ciphertext[] = "D06BF9D0DAB8E8EF880660D2AF65AA82";

    unsigned int startSeed = 1524020929;


    unsigned char cipher[7201][128];
    int cipher_len;

    // 2 hours is 7200 seconds
    //printf("Beginning keygen\n");
    for(i = 0; i <= (7200); i++){
    
        srand(i + startSeed);
        //printf("Here\n");
        for(int j = 0; j < KEYSIZE; j++){
        
            //printf("Assigning key value\n");
            key[i][j] = rand() % 256;
            //printf("%.2x", (unsigned char)key[j]);
        }
        //printf("\n");
        cipher_len = encrypt(plaintext, strlen((char *)plaintext), key[i], iv, cipher[i]);
        //printf("%d\n", sizeof(cipher));
        //BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char *)cipher, cipher_len);
    
        if(memcmp(cipher[i], ciphertext, 128) == 0){
            printf("found matching ciphertext");
        
        }
    }
  }
```

Do I need to convert each cipher[i] to a hex string before comparison?

Edit:
I wrote a bash script to try to do the same thing, and see if I can compare the base64 encoding of the ciphertexts, but no luck. I am very inexperienced with bash scripting and I still don't have a solid grasp on the data types I should be passing into the encryption:

[image: Bash script]

Edit 2: Here is the procedure I used to generate the starting seed. The lab manual says that Alice created a pdf file at "2018-04-17 23:08:49". I used a date command  `date -d "2018-04-17 23:08:49" +%s` to get the number of seconds since the starting epoch. This is what I used as the starting seed. The lab also states that it is known that Alice generated the key between this starting time and 2 hours later, which is why I set the end of the seed range to startSeed + 7200.

Last edit:
After the changes I finally got it to work. I made it so that I am generating seeds in the proper time window, and I made it so that AES algorithm does not add padding.

Additionally, I only allocate 16 bytes to my ciphertext arrays, and changed memcmp to look at 16 bytes only. After these changes I was able to reproduce the known ciphertext.

Comment: IV, plaintext and ciphertext seem to be hex encoded and must then first be hex decoded. In addition, the ciphertext is only 16 bytes large, so that only 16 bytes are to be allocated per ciphertext and also to be compared later. Furthermore, the padding is probably to be disabled. Also, using `srand`/`rand` as key derivation may be problematic: Is the implementation really  _guaranteed and always_ identical? And finally: How reliable are IV, plaintext, ciphertext and especially the computed start seed?

Comment: Hey @Topaco, by hex decoded, do you mean to something like a byte array? Or decimal? And to your question, using srand and rand to derive the key is the point of this lab, to show that if you know the seed was generated based upon the time, and you know what time it was generated, then I suppose you could generate the same key. So I assume that for the purposes of this lab, we are supposed to eventually yield the same known ciphertext as the one that was given.

Comment: As far as reliability of the given IV, plaintext/ciphertext pair, I have copied them directly from the lab manual.

Comment: A hex encoded string `D06B...AA82` can be hex decoded statically e.g. with `unsigned char ciphertext[] = { 0xD0, 0x6B..., 0xAA, 0x82 };`. How did you determine the seed and why should `startSeed + i, (i = 0,1,...,7200)` apply to the seed? You should post the specifications from the lab.

Comment: I will edit my post showing how I determined the starting seed.

Comment: https://seedsecuritylabs.org/Labs_20.04/Files/Crypto_Random_Number/Crypto_Random_Number.pdf , see task 2 for reference to the lab details. I will try to format my input ciphertext and plaintext as you have shown, and run my code again.

Comment: `key[i][j] = rand() % 256;`? How do you know that only the lowest-order byte from `rand()` was used to generate the key byte-by-byte?

Comment: According to the description, the key was generated in the 2h time window _before_ the timestamp, which rather means `startSeed - i`. Also, you'll probably need to fix the other issues mentioned besides encoding to make it work.

Comment: Hey Topaco, thanks for clarifying that for me, that's probably why I haven't gotten a match yet.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, this is how the key was generated in the sample program they provided in the lab manual, so I'm using the same method.

Comment: Finally got it to work, listed the changes I made in the last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fixes that I made to use the proper seed range and statically decode the hex input strings, what was the most broken in my implementation was comparing a 16-byte long char array with a 128 byte long char array. I changed the generated cipher text char arrays to only be 16 bytes long, as well as only comparing 16 bytes at a time in memcmp().